# Why does the jquery ajax call erase the current data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that calls in a new html file, to be added into a div. I'm wondering why the content in the div is replaced rather than just added in. Once I understand the "why" Id like to know how I would add in external markup into a div while preserving what was already in that div to begin with.

```
 $.ajax({
 url: 't3.html',
 success: function(data) {
 $('.ajax').html(data);
 }
 });
```

Comment: Well, `.html` by design replaces the data. Are you looking for http://api.jquery.com/append/ ?

Comment: yip, that is why. Thats not readily apparent looking at the jquery api, thanks for the tip! What if I only wanted to load in the contents of a particular div from the external file? I tried url: 't3.html#test', but it stioll loads in the entire page. If you could leave the answer instead of comment, i can give you credit for the first answer. Thanks!

Comment: nah, just select one of the answers below, that's fine. Re loading the contents, I don't remember what the syntax was, it should be in the docs; it *could* be that there needs to be a space between `t3.html` and `#test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('.ajax').html(data);
```

use:

```
$('.ajax').append(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

try `.append`

```
 $.ajax({
 url: 't3.html',
 success: function(data) {
   $('.ajax').append(data);
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are replacing the whole HTML of .ajax div with data. If you want to preserve the existing HTML of that control use the following
 $('.ajax').html($('.ajax').html() + data);d